# Mid 2010 MacBook Pro and Thunderbolt display

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

Is there a way to use Thunderbolt display with mid 2010 MacBook Pro that only has a Mini DisplayPort (i.e. no Thunderbolt)? I understand that Thunderbolt displays are officially supposed to work only with post 2010 Macs, however I only care about the display functionality, i.e. I want my Mac to simply see it as a monitor.

Answer (score -2):

Try a thunderbolt to mini display port adapter. Should be sold at the apple store or for cheaper on Amazon.

Comment: Are you sure such thing exists in Apple store?